# bootstrap calendar javascript alert in cakephp

Tags: jquery, cakephp, twitter-bootstrap, calendar, alert

well, i am try to use this calendar in cakephp and it works.
`https://github.com/ahmontero/bootstrap-calendar`

I am a very new and never learn jquery before. ok now i wish to did some modification on this calendar source. As u see inside the `demo.html` got that js code.

```
.on('onEvent', function(event){ 
    alert(event.day.valueOf() +'-'+ event.month.valueOf() +'-'+ event.year.valueOf()); 
})
```

The `onEvent` will alert out the date as we picked as events day. Well, my question is .. how to change the word of that alert. I want it alert as my database data.

Example: i want it `alert(<?php echo $date['Calender']['description']; ?>);` when i onclick the event days as i done setup?
any help ?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to alert "Hello world" when the "onEvent" event is fired, try this

```
 .on('onEvent', function(event){ alert("Hello world"); })
```

Comment: sorry pals, i means i need to alert some data from my database . i edited my post already